# Maps in Android CardView in Recycler View

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to inflate a card view in a Recycler adapter view and I get an error like their is no such instance as kasualjob which im.
Here is my adapter

```
public class KasualJobAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KasualJobAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    protected LatLng mMapLocation;
    private List<KasualJob> kasualjobList;
    private FragmentManager fragmentmanager;

    public KasualJobAdapter(List<KasualJob> kasualjobList, FragmentManager fragmentmanager) {
        this.kasualjobList = kasualjobList;
        this.fragmentmanager = fragmentmanager;
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView kasualjobtitle, kasualjobdescription, kasualjoblocation, kasualjobdateposted, kasualjobuser;
        public SupportMapFragment kasualjobmap;

        public MyViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);

            kasualjobtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_name);
            kasualjobdescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_description);
            kasualjoblocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_location);
            kasualjobdateposted = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_date_time_posted);
            kasualjobuser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_user);

            kasualjobmap = (SupportMapFragment)fragmentmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.kasual_job_mapview);

            kasualjobmap.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    mMap = googleMap;

                    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                }
            });
        }

        public void setMapLocation(double lat, double lon) {
            mMapLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);

            if (mMap != null) {
                updateMapContents();
            }
        }

        protected void updateMapContents() {
            mMap.clear();
            // Update the mapView feature data and camera position.
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mMapLocation));
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMapLocation, 10f);
            mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.kasual_job_card_view, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        KasualJob kasualJob=kasualjobList.get(position);
        holder.kasualjobtitle.setText(kasualJob.getKasualjobtypename());
        holder.kasualjobdescription.setText(kasualJob.getKasualjobdescription());
        holder.kasualjoblocation.setText("For Know its Utalii,Nairobi,Kenya");
        holder.setMapLocation(kasualJob.getKasualjoblatitude(), kasualJob.getJoblongitude());
        holder.kasualjobdateposted.setText("On " + kasualJob.getKasualjobdatetimeposted());
        holder.kasualjobuser.setText("By " + kasualJob.getUserfirstname()+ " "+ kasualJob.getUserlastname());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return kasualjobList.size();
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me out so that I can render the maps and if possible explain to me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: The xml viewholder would also be good to know.

Comment: The Error log. 07-20 11:01:55.191 4530-4530/com.kasualjobs.kasualjobs E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: xml view---<fragmentclass="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:id="@+id/kasual_job_mapview"/>

Answer (score 0):

try to move

```
holder.kasualjobmap.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }
    });
```

Into the method  `onBindViewHolder.`